# How to populate a complex object using Linq to Sql

Tags: c#, linq

I am new to Linq. I have to use Linq to Sql to project data from sql server to a complex object. The complex object is the Employee class which has another class, EmployeeDetail, as a property.  I am able to populate the Employee class but unable to populate the EmployeeDetail. I have enclosed my code below. Obviously, I have to instantiate EmployeeDetail within the select new Employee block and attach it. Unfortunately, I don't know how to do it.

```
public class Employee
{
    public String Email { get; set; }        
    public String EmployeeId { get; set; }   
    public EmployeeDetail employeeDetail { get; set; }    
}

public class EmployeeDetail
{
    public String PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public String Address { get; set; }
}

public class Data
{
    public List<Employee> GetEmployee()
    {
        EmployeeDataContext dbDontext = new EmployeeDataContext ();

        var employees = from i in dbDontext.Employee
                    join m in dbDontext.Employee on i.Employee_Id equals 
                    m.Emplyee_Detail_Id
                    select new Employee
                    {
                        Email = i.email,
                        EmployeeId = i.employee_Id.ToString(),
                        //how to get data for the EmployeeDetail property 
                        //with PhoneNumber  and Address values populated?
                    };
        var employeeList = employees.ToList();
        return employeeList;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not really a LINQ question, more of an object initializer question.  When you are initializing an object, you can set its properties:

```
new Employee
{
    Email = i.email,
    EmployeeId = i.employee_Id.ToString() 
}
```

The same syntax is true of its object type properties:

```
new Employee
{
    Email = i.email,
    EmployeeId = i.employee_Id.ToString(),
    employeeDetail = new EmployeeDetail
    {
        PhoneNumber = ...,
        Address = ...
    }
}
```